# Yii2: how to build query properly using Query Builder

Tags: yii2, query-builder

I'm using Yii2 and I have such query now:

```
   $data = $modelClass::find()->select([
    'task_group.*', 
    'count' => 'COUNT(task.id)',
    'processed_count' => 'SUM(CASE WHEN task.status=\''.Task::STATUS_PROCESSED.'\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
    'unprocessed_count' => 'SUM(CASE WHEN task.status=\''.Task::STATUS_UNPROCESSED.'\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)',
    'problem_count' => 'SUM(CASE WHEN task.status=\''.Task::STATUS_PROBLEM.'\' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)'])
        ->joinWith('tasks')          
        ->groupBy('task_group.id')->all();
```

But I think there must be some better way in Yii2 to represent it. How can I rewrite it properly? For example, without inline parameters.

Comment: Hmm. This is one instance where I think you should not convert it. It is a lot more readable in this format.

Comment: Can I use placeholders for Task::STATUS_PROCESSED and other familiar constants then in this query? I saw then in Yii2 DAO, but not in query builder.

Answer (score 0):

Now I see, it can be done in such way:

```
task.status=:status_processed
...
->addParams([':status_processed' => Task::STATUS_PROCESSED])
```